# Error, could not create MachMessagePort for database doctor (com.apple.addressbook.migrationdaemon) starting in process migration

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working in address book for iphone.
it generate address into UILabel.
when I'm running the application everything goes well, but after showing about %30 of the addresses and sadenly stopped without any reason!
Only in terminal shows:
**Error, could not create MachMessagePort for database doctor (com.apple.addressbook.migrationdaemon) starting in process migration**

Please help me!

Comment: I am also facing the same problem.. plz suggest...

Alish have you fine and solution of this issue.

thx

Comment: It was long time ago. I don''t remember but the problem has forget to release one of the object.

[theObject release];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem...
the object i found that needed to be released was the `ABAddressBookRef` it's self... looks like you can only have so many (242 on the sim.) address book refs before it hangs.... :P

Hope this helps... :)

Answer (score 0):

It was long time ago.
I don''t remember but the problem has forget to release one of the object.

```
[theObject release];
```